# Make the state of multiple checkboxes Checked in Angular depending on the received data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I want to mark multiple checkboxes checked based on the data I retrieve or in other words keep there state the same as when the form was submitted,
I have a form with multiple checkboxes in it, and there is also an edit button which allows me to edit the form while it was easy to retrieve the same data for `input[text]` I'm unable to figure out how can I change the state of checkboxes to Checked as the data I receive is in form of an array which looks like this `["M", "3XL", "7XL", "10XL"]`.

[image]

Now I want to keep those checkboxes checked when the form was submitted when the user click's edit button.

**Component.ts**

```
  checkArrayEBXBR = [];
  checkArrayJEBXO = [];
  checkboxObject = [
    {
      checkboxLabel: "EBXBR",
      checkboxContainer: [
        {
          id: "0",
          label: "S",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          label: "M",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          label: "L",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          label: "XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          label: "2XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "5",
          label: "3XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "6",
          label: "4XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "7",
          label: "5XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "8",
          label: "6XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "9",
          label: "7XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "10",
          label: "8XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "11",
          label: "9XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "12",
          label: "10XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      checkboxLabel: "JEBXO",
      checkboxContainer: [
        {
          id: "0",
          label: "S",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          label: "M",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          label: "L",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          label: "XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          label: "2XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "5",
          label: "3XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "6",
          label: "4XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "7",
          label: "5XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "8",
          label: "6XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "9",
          label: "7XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "10",
          label: "8XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "11",
          label: "9XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
        {
          id: "12",
          label: "10XL",
          isChecked: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  changeSelection() {
    this.fetchSelectedItems();
  }
  fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.ebxbrselectedItemsList = this.checkboxObject[0].checkboxContainer.filter(
      (value, index) => {
        return value.isChecked;
      }
    );
    this.checkArrayEBXBR = [];
    this.checkArrayJEBXO = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.ebxbrselectedItemsList.length; i++) {
      this.checkArrayEBXBR.push(this.ebxbrselectedItemsList[i].label);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.jebxoselectedItemsList.length; i++) {
      this.checkArrayJEBXO.push(this.jebxoselectedItemsList[i].label);
    }
    console.log(this.checkArrayJEBXO)
    console.log(this.checkArrayEBXBR)
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group selection-container">
          <h5 class="form-title">SKU</h5>
          <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of checkboxObject; let i = index">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group size-code">
                <ion-label class="item-code">{{item.checkboxLabel}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox slot="end" value="pepperoni"></ion-checkbox>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="sizes-container">
                <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let innerItem of checkboxObject[i].checkboxContainer">
                  <ion-label for="{{item.id}}" >{{ innerItem.label }}</ion-label>
                  <ion-checkbox
                    slot="end"
                    [(ngModel)]="innerItem.isChecked"
                    (ionChange)="changeSelection()"
                    name="{{ innerItem.isChecked }}"
                    [value]="innerItem.label"
                    id="{{innerItem.id}}"
                  ></ion-checkbox>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

as you can also notice there are 2 sets of checkboxes and for each of them I have created a separate array, And I have many more of these sets I if there is a better way than making an array for each of them I would be thankfull to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the checkboxes to be checked, the `<ion-checkbox>` has a property called `checked` and you can use it to bind with a value.. something like this in your case:

```
<ion-checkbox
          slot="end"
          [(ngModel)]="innerItem.isChecked"
          (ionChange)="changeSelection()"
          name="{{ innerItem.isChecked }}"
          [value]="innerItem.label"
          id="{{innerItem.id}}"
          [checked]="innerItem.isChecked" // Add this line. 
></ion-checkbox>
```

That attribute will keep the checkbox checked if the value is true.